# How to use server tag inside alert()?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, window, alert, resx

Perhaps this is a stupid thing to ask but the already available solutions didn't seem to work for me.

I have a Resources.resx file and I am trying to use this inside an `alert()`

Here's what I did.

```
if(obj)
{
   myMethod();
}
else
{
   alert(<%= Resources.Nill %>);
}
```

I also tried to use quotes like `alert("<%= Resources.Nill %>");` (both single and double) but then the output generated is `<%= Resources.Nill %>` on the screen.

I want the value the Resource holds to be showed when `else` is executed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's unnecessary (and often frowned on) to start your question with 'stupid thing...'

Comment: well you are not quoting it so that is one issue `alert("<%= Resources.Nill %>");`